# Rails 7 SortableJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, sortablejs

i have a rails app and it contains stripe for payment, my console shows Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://js.stripe.com
') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost:3000') . it was not showing this before, but as soon as i integrated SortableJS library and implemented it using stimulus , drag and sort started working but now i get this error in console

Main key point is that when i first visit a certain link , it shows me the error message in console, but when i refresh the page, the error is fixed.

Conclusion: Everytime when i visit a certain link, i need to refresh the page once to fix this error :') anyone knows why this error is showing after i implemented SortableJS using stimulus? :' )
[image]